# Plugin in Maven and pom.xml file

Tags: pom.xml, maven-plugin

I've got the following error in pom.xml file:

[image]

The content of pom.xml where the error appears:

```
   <properties> 
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding> 
      <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding> 
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> 
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
      <maven-compiler-pluging.version>3.2</maven-compiler-pluging.version>
   </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin> ===> ERROR APPEARS HERE
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshot.

Comment: Post the values of the `${maven-compiler-plugin.version}` and `${java.version}` in the `<properties>` too.

Comment: @Raduan Santos. It's already there.                                                                        <properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
   
   <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
   
   <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   <maven-compiler-pluging.version>3.2</maven-compiler-pluging.version>
   
   
  </properties>

Comment: I saw that your plugin is using the version from `${maven-compiler-plugin.version}` but your property is named `maven-compiler-pluging.version`. Isn't this your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maven-compiler-plugin is using a version from the property `${maven-compiler-plugin.version}` who doesn't exist.

Your property is named `maven-compiler-pluging.version` with an extra **g**.

Comment: Sorry ! My bad. It's time to change my glasses. Lol. Thank you so much.